# How do I display real-time graphs from fetching data from excel file and plotting the data after 5 sec in graph using python

Tags: python, excel

Here is my code,I have to fetch the data from excel file and it is fetching two column, and I have also used "gridsepec" for showing each graph in different axes, but I want each data should plot after each 5 second till the last row of the excel sheet, and in real time using python and if possible add a button to show the data value in the Button according to the value it is plotting in the graph:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# read  from excel file
wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Acer-i5-607\\Desktop\\case1.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('case1')

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4), facecolor='Grey')
G = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 2)
axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[0, :])


x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=4).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('HR')
plt.plot(x, y, color='cyan', label='HR')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)
#plt.title('Reading values from an Excel file'

axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[1, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=6).value

#print a
#print b

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Pulse')
plt.plot(x, y, color='red', label='Pulse')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)


axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[2, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=7).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('SpO2')
plt.plot(x, y, color='magenta', label='SpO2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)


axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[3, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=8).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('Perf')
plt.plot(x, y, color='blue', label='Perf')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)


axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[4, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=9).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('etCO2')
plt.plot(x, y, color='yellow', label='etCO2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)


axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[5, :])

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=10).value

#print x
#print y

# create the plot
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('imCO2')
plt.plot(x, y, color='green', label='imCO2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize='small')
plt.grid(True)

plt.xlim(0, 60000)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow. How about making a small example of your problem and provide some data? Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Until then -1.

Comment: RelativeTimeMilliseconds    HR Pulse SpO2 Perf
0                                      55 55         10         0.1
10                                      65 56         100         0.2
20                                      75 57         200         0.3
30                                      85 58         300         0.4

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer after many try hope it will help someone too:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import tkinter
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


wb = load_workbook('C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\case1.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('case1')
# simulates input from serial port

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4), facecolor='Grey')
G = gridspec.GridSpec(6, 2)

x = np.zeros(sheet_1.max_row)
y = np.zeros(len(x))
z = np.zeros(len(x))
a = np.zeros(len(x))
b = np.zeros(len(x))
c = np.zeros(len(x))
d = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(1, sheet_1.max_row):
    x[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=2).value
    y[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=4).value
    z[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=6).value
    a[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=7).value
    b[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=8).value
    c[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=9).value
    d[i] = sheet_1.cell(row=i + 1, column=10).value
    plt.ion()

#print(x[i])
#print("Printed ................")
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
list4 = []
list5 = []
list6 = []
list7 = []
#print("---------------------------------")
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    #print("Inside Loop ....")
    list1.append(x[i])

    list2.append(y[i])
    list3.append(z[i])
    list4.append(a[i])
    list5.append(b[i])
    list6.append(c[i])
    list7.append(d[i])
    #print(list1[i], list2[i], end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
    plt.plot(list1, list2, color='cyan', label='HR')
    plt.plot(list1, list3, color='red', label='Pulse')
    plt.plot(list1, list4, color='yellow', label='Spo2')
    plt.plot(list1, list5, color='green', label='Perf')
    plt.plot(list1, list6, color='magenta', label='etCO2')
    plt.plot(list1, list7, color='pink', label='imCO2')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.pause(0.5)
```